# UX to VD Workflow

Tags: workflow, design-process

Just got hired to create an in-house UX/UI VD team. My first task is to create a process outline of how our team will produce all our work, which will consist mainly of redesigning various corp websites. I've got a lot of experience in various roles, but have never had to spec out a start-to-finish workflow and task assignments. I'm looking for any books, websites or other reference materials that I can study to begin designing and implementing a robust system and workflow. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a little more context? Since I am personally familiar of the corporate world could you address the needs of redesigning various websites? Is it small changes or are they willing to invest for a full redesign?

Comment: What's important to understand here is that UX to VD (UI) is still to many degrees dependent on the underlying business processes and technology, and it is often something that is missed in the design decisions and rationale.

Answer (score 2):

From your description seems that neither you nor them have any clue of how the process is going to go.
What is going to actually happen is going be unveiled in the near future.
There are many things you can do in UX design but you'll always have to choose something within the time & money resources you are given.

Until then, your clients need a reassurance that you are going provide work that is meaningful and profitable for them.

So here I'm quoting a hypothetical 12-month performance review. It could look like this:

> *You worked with our largest client to design and implement a long-term UX strategy that supports their business goals. You devised new and innovative large-scale projects in line with this strategy, and got the client excited to participate. You built strong one-on-one relationships with multiple client stakeholders, to the point where you can call them up to ask a question or request a favor without hesitation, and they’re always happy to hear from you.*
>
> *You initiated a program of bi-weekly live user research that supports all 12 IT product teams at a Fortune 500 company. You helped build a 300-person research panel and an end-to-end study process. Your innovative marketing of the program led to a 2-month waitlist for new studies — plus overflow observation rooms with lots of first-timers. You ensured the program’s longevity by training in-house designers on recruiting, moderating and other parts of your process. The company is now building out a full-time research lab.*
>
> *You crafted and implemented a set of product strategies for a Fortune 500 company’s mobile app. You partnered with data geeks, designers and analysts to deeply understand why customers were abandoning a core transaction. You then guided the team to a solution that decreased support calls by 30% within 3 months.*
>
> *As UX owner for our new, B2B e-commerce client, you collaborated with stakeholders to develop short- and long-term strategic goals. You worked with other Marketade consultants and our PM to ensure that our efforts were coordinated and aligned with client goals. You led 2 usability testing initiatives, and helped the client reach a deeper understanding of their users. Your recommended changes to the client’s lead generation flow led to a 20% increase in form completions.*
>
> *You expanded the Marketade UX team by 1 junior UX specialist and 1 intern. You worked with the UX team lead to develop and spearhead a Marketade UX Apprenticeship program, which onboards a new UX intern every 6 months, allowing UX specialists to focus on higher-end projects and practice mentorship.*

You can derive what needs to be done from the above. Like bind with real numbers to goals that make a difference in the business.
Of course you could start explaining all the steps that need to take place but do not treat it like another mandatory process that consumes resources.
This is a great chance to express that UX matters and how.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely just my own process (so disclaimer here if it doesn't work for you), but I haven't really seen anything that bridges the gaps between system, UI and UX design that is being practised out there, so I just did my own thing:

[image]

What you can do with a strategy like this is to figure out whether it is the business processes, UI or UX that needs to be redesigned, and how they need to align in terms of the standards and guidelines that you lay out for getting the work done. As you can see, there are many artefacts or assets that can be created to document each of the separate pieces of work. Obviously this is just a generic and simplified version, but perhaps a starting point for you?